# How can I generate dynamic parameters in jenkins build pipeline using active choice parameter by reading from a file?

Tags: parameters, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

Currently I am using the following piece of code to generate dynamic parameters by reading from a properties file using the 'groovy script' option in 'active choice parameter'

```
jenkinsURL=jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getRootUrl()

def propFile="build_choices.properties" //name of properties file
def propKey="test" // name of properties key
def relPropFileUrl="userContent/" // userContent/properties/
def propAddress="${jenkinsURL}${relPropFileUrl}$propFile"
def props= new Properties()
props.load(new URL(propAddress).openStream())
def choices=[]

props.get(propKey.toString()).split(",").each{
  choices.add(it)
    }

return choices
```

This is currently working in version 'ver. 2.60.3' but does not work in higher versions eg: 'ver. 2.102'. Is there a solution that works across all the versions?

Answer (score 1):

I just found out, there is actually a much easier way to read parameters from a property file using  [Extended Choice Parameter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin).

You have to provide 'Parameter Type' and 'Delimiter' in 'Basic Parameter Types' and select the 'Choose Source for Value' option to provide the 'Property file' path and 'Property key' values.